# If the string matches multiple times, increase the counter by 1

Tags: ruby, function

I have a small script, where i am matching a string and if the string is matched multiple times the counter should increase by one.

```
def watch_for(file, pattern)
  f = File.open(file,"r")
  f.seek(0,IO::SEEK_END)

  while true do
    select([f])
    line = f.gets

    if line =~ pattern
      counter = 0
      counter += 1

      if counter == 4
        puts counter
      end
    end
  end


watch_for(file, test)
```

When each line in the file is compared to the pattern and when string "test" is matched, the counter should be increased by 1 and when counter becomes 4 it should print string "counter", but the counter resets to "0" every time it matches the pattern and wont execute the if condition. Is there a way to get this done. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Instead of `while true` use `loop do`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple problems with your code, the first is that that [`seek`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#method-i-seek) line

```
f.seek(0,IO::SEEK_END)
```

is seeking to 0 bytes past the end of the file, or in otherwords, the end of the file. If you were trying to make sure you are at the beginning of the file (which I believe is unnecessary in Ruby), you could use [`rewind`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#method-i-rewind) instead.

Next, you are resetting your counter on every line that matches your pattern, you should move the

```
counter = 0
```

up, outside the loop, for instance, right beneath where you open the file:

```
f = File.open(file,"r")
counter = 0
```

Lastly, you're never closing the file, which is just a good habit you should get into:

```
f.close
```

---

If you're allowed to use a built in method to do this, you should look at [`grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep)

> Returns an array of every element in enum for which Pattern === element. If the optional block is supplied, each matching element is passed to it, and the block's result is stored in the output array.

```
# calling File.open with a block will automatically
# close the file at the end of the block
matched_lines = File.open("./bacon_ipsum.txt") do |file|
  counter = 0
  file.grep(/bacon/i) do |matching_line|
    counter += 1
    puts counter if counter == 4

    matching_line
  end
end

puts "found #{matched_lines.length} matching lines"
```

Comment: This only shows the counter on instance #4. It probably should show it every 4th line, or `counter % 4 == 0`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the original code was doing a sort of `tail -f` on the file by seeking to the end and waiting for new data with `select`.

Comment: Yeah the `tail -f` was the first thing I mentioned...didn't occur me to they may have meant to be doing that, though seeing it in terms of `tail -f` that's entirely possible. They code the posted showed it only outputting on the fourth line, and the description says "when it reaches 4, output", but yeah modding by 4 would work to show for every 4th line

Answer (score 0):

move `counter = 0` line out of the while loop